# nodejs regex - why do we need "?" in the following regex

Tags: regex, node.js

I have a question regarding the following regex:

```
match = /^([^[]+?)(\[.*\])?$/.exec(path);
```

I don't understand the behavior of the "?" in the first expression:

```
^([^[]+?)
```

I mean, if this expression was an independent regex, and path was "abc[def]", I would have got: "a" as match[1], right? (due to the lazy match).
Now, when I add the second expression, match[1] is: "abc".
Could you please explain the difference?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: @SamIam that's incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` in a construction like `+?` or `*?` causes the operator preceding it to behave in a non-greedy, or lazy, fashion.  This means it will consume as few characters as possible instead of as many as possible (as is the default).

However, in this particular regex, there are no strings for which the `?` changes the behavior.

```
/^([^[]+?)(\[.*\])?$/
```

Since the first group `([^[]+?)` must be followed by either the end of the string or a `[` and the first group can't contain a `[`, it will match either the entire string (if no `[` in it) or up to the first `[`, or it won't match at all.  So in this case, the greediness of `+` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

if you use `?` you are actually saying ,

- may or may not
- `lazy` matching

`ab?` is `a` with or  without `b` ( one time only)

but in this format :

`a+?` is : "try search a's but don't be greedy"

so only the first [a] in [aaaaaaa] will be matched here.

## edit

```
/^([^[]+?)/.exec("abc[def]");  //["a", "a"]
```

why is that ?

becuase you are searching

from the start----everything not including `[` but search the min occurences.

thats your `a`

but when youre doing

```
/^([^[]+?)(\[.*\])?$/.exec("abc[def]");
```

the one which congusing you is :

`.*` in the secong group.

Comment: Yes, so if the path is "abc[def]", why do I get "abc" as match[1] and not just "a"?

Comment: @user429400 what makes you think you will match only `a` ?

Comment: when I try it with this expression: /^([^[]+?)/ and this path: "abs[def]" it only matches "a" (I'm testing it with the node console)

Comment: sorry for being so hard, but the second group only affects the matching inside each pair of [], isn't it? shouldn't it only mean: match everything between "[" and "]" ? why should it affect the matching of the first group, which matches the characters before the first "["?

Comment: In addition, when I try this expression with and without the "?" in the first group, the result stays the same. It's like it has no effect at all.

Answer (score 2):

The `?` after the `+` swaps the behaviour of the regex engine to ungreedy. By default the engine tries to match the largest string available. With a trailing `?` it tries to get the shortest.

More information are available here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: yes, but again, it seems like the second expression somehow changes this behavior...

Comment: the second expression `(\[.*\])?` matches anything like "[stuff here]" at the end of the string. The `?` at this place allows this stuff to appear max once.

Comment: ok, I understand the second expression. Indeed it matches everything between the first "[" and the last "]". I don't understand what is the meaning of the "?" in the first expression. I thought it should mean: match 0 or 1 chars which are not "[". turns out it doesn't change anything, it seems like it does not have any effect.